# How to implement native Google Play In-app billing in a libGDX project?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, aidl

I was following [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service) and stuck at "a. Navigate to src/main in the Project tool window."

Because I couldn't find src/main in my project structure (Neither in the explorer)

[image]

Like it is shown here:

[image]

I think it's because I'm working with a libGDX project.

---

I tried adding the Module directly under the src (As if I was not working in a android studio environment), but when I build my application, I don't see a generated file named IInAppBillingService.java anywhere.

[image]

Comment: It appears that the instructions are for an older version of Android Studio.

Comment: okay, there is something odd going on here. I will look into it and get back to you shortly.

Comment: After rereading your question, I see that you are asking about the generated .java file. This is most likely in the `build` directory of your project. To this point, I have been focusing on the project directory structure.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I actually did found it. After cleaning and rebuilding, I tried to safe remove the .aidl and it pointed me to the location of .java which was located in '$PROJECT\android\build\generated\source\aidl\debug\com\android\vending\billing'

Comment: I apologize for any confusion on my part. I originally read your question as "Where is the src/main folder? And where should I place my AIDL file?" when the real question is probably more along the lines of "Where is my .java file that should be generated from the AIDL?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open `build.gradle` in the `android` folder of your project, you will see the following block of Gradle code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
```

This block configures where Gradle looks for source files. LibGDX uses this to customize the directory hierarchy which is why you are unable to exactly follow the steps given in the Android documentation.

Now the line `aidl.srcDirs = ['src']` tells us that the project is configured so that all AIDL files can be placed directly in the `src` folder. So you can modify the step to navigate to `src/main` and instead just go directly to `src`. Follow the rest of the instructions from there. If Android Studio balks at any step, you may have to go directly to the file system using the command line or your favorite file explorer in order to create the folders and files that you need.

It appears you have done this and the second part (or maybe the primary part?) of your question is the location of the generated .java file from your AIDL source. Android Studio places all generated artifacts under the `build` directory. There is a `build` folder directly in the base directory of your project and one in each module. Search these for the generated file.

Comment: I already mentioned on the previous answer that I am using the Project View, and that the src/main isn't found in the explorer either.

Comment: @Matta Please update your question with a screen shot. Be sure to expand to `<project name>/android` to show what folder are in that directory.

Comment: @Matta Also, I have edited my answer to make it more concise and hopefully more helpful.

Comment: @Matta Be sure to include the entire Project pane in your screenshots. You cut off the pane's menu bar in the original ones. (I am referring to the bar with either "Android" or "Project" and several buttons, not the bar with "File", etc.)

Comment: I updated it. And if I go to Android View and try to do alt+insert it only allows me to add a module or a packet, not a directory or a folder. (Only the Android Resource Directory)

Comment: @Matta Maybe the third time is the charm. Check out my newest answer and let me know what other kinks we need to iron out.

Comment: I was actually looking into that, but after rebuilding I couldn't see the .java in the hierarchy which made me think It wasn't generated but It was there all along, and only after trying to refactor and safe remove the .aidl it pointed out the location of .java

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-N is also helpful for searching for files. Just type a file name.

Comment: @Matta Forgot to ping you in my previous comment. If you saw it alerady, ignore this.